# Initialize database on web automate testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, selenium, bdd

I got an asp.net MVC application which uses MongoDB database.
Im auto-testing (BDD) it with SpecFlow and Selenium WebDriver, and I want to initialize my database to some state before navigating to some URL or making some acrions. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Yes we can do it. I had been already testing my application by selenium webdriver which uses mongodb. I am using a functional driven framework in case of bdd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do that ?

yes!

I've did that in the following way:

1.When tests initialize - generate test database (in most simple way via driver).

```
users.Insert(new User(){ Id: "1", userName: "testUser" })
```

2.Make backup (I've used mongodump to do that)

3.Before test starts create db with unique name myApp_tests_guid. Keep db name somewhere.

4.Restore database (mongorestore)

5.When test finish or in case of failure -- drop database.

6.Optional step for the some specific tests is to adjust common tests database with test specific data.

That's it. The reason why I've used backup/restore approach was performance. Also for the tests make sure that you've disabled safe mode and journaling -- it will make things faster.

Comment: Can you elaborate about generating test database ? I did nit find anything about it on the web .. Btw, I am using selenium webdriver with c#

Comment: I just did it manually via official c# driver, as you can see above at #1.